# setState through Context not setting state (NextJS)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-context

I'm taking my first pass at using NextJS, and also my first pass at using a headless CMS (DatoCMS in this case).

Everything was actually working fine, but I found myself using a lot of prop drilling, to get information returned from the CMS down into deeply nested components, and that was becoming cumbersome. After some googling, I decided to try to use React Context to avoid prop drilling as described [here](https://www.technouz.com/5131/using-react-context-to-avoid-prop-drilling-on-a-next-js-generated-page/).

The first use case is getting site branding info and menu items down to the nav component (this info will almost always be the same, everywhere on the site, but there might be some sections (e.g., landing pages) where they're different).

The problem is, the React useState set function as passed through the ContextProvider doesn't actually seem to set the state. There are several questions on here about state not being updated in various scenarios, but this isn't setting the initial state after NextJS grabs the data from `getStaticProps`<s>, but here it's not doing it even if I manually call the set function directly in the component wrapped in ContextProvider, never mind somewhere farther down the stack</s>.

As described in that blog post, I have the context provider pulled out into its own component:

```
// context/header.js
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react';

const HeaderContext = createContext();

export function HeaderProvider({children}) {
    const [header, setHeader] = useState(null);

    const value = { header, setHeader };

    return (
        <HeaderContext.Provider value={value}>
            {children}
        </HeaderContext.Provider>
    )
}

export function useHeader() {
    return useContext(HeaderContext);
}
```

Then, in `_app.js`, I wrap my `<Header />` component in the context provider:

```
// pages/_app.js
import Header from '../components/Header';
import { HeaderProvider } from '../lib/context/header';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <>
      <HeaderProvider>
        <Header { ...pageProps } /> 
      </HeaderProvider>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </>
  )
}

export default MyApp
```

I'm just starting this out, so right now, everything is designed to be a static page (no server side rendering or client side React yet).

The main page, from `index.js`, successfully grabs the data from DatoCMS:

```
// pages/index.js
import { request } from "../lib/datocms";
import { HOMEPAGE_QUERY } from '../lib/query';

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const data = await request({
    query: HOMEPAGE_QUERY
  });
  return {
    props: { data }
  };
}

export default function Home({ data }) {
  return (
    <div>
      This is the home page
    </div>
  );
}
```

So far, this is working, because in my `<Header />` component, I can log the data passed.

As I understand how NextJS works, that `getStaticProps` call populates `pageProps` which get passed back to the Component (the page) to generate the static html. The results of the `request` call in `getStaticProps` is in fact making it's way back to `pageProps` to be used both in the `<Component />` and the `<Header />` in `_app.js`, but when I try to use the `setHeader()` function from `header.js`, pulled in by calling `useHeader()`, the value of the stateful `header` is always `null`.

```
// components/Header.js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useHeader } from '../lib/context/header';
import Navbar from './Navbar';

export default function Header({data}) {
    const HeaderData = {
        siteName: data.siteBranding.siteName,
        companyLogo: data.siteBranding.companyLogo,
        menu: data?.menu
    };
    console.log(HeaderData);
    // outputs:
    // {
    //   siteName: 'My Site',
    //   companyLogo: {
    //     alt: 'My Site Logo',
    //     height: 113,
    //     url: 'https://www.datocms-assets.com/<url>',
    //     width: 122
    //   },
    //   menu: { title: 'primary', menuItems: [ [Object], [Object] ] }
    // }

    const { setHeader } = useHeader();

    useEffect(() => {
      setHeader(HeaderData)
    }, [HeaderData]);
    
    return (
        <header>
            <Navbar />
        </header>
    )
}
```

And then using the context in `<Navbar />`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useHeader } from '../lib/context/header';

export default function Navbar() {
    const { header } = useHeader();
    console.log(header); // null :(

    return (
        <div>This is my nav</div>
    )
}
```

How do I actually get my context state into `<Navbar />`?

<s>The problem is, the `header` context in `<Navbar />` is always the initial state of `null`. There was [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62651899/react-unable-to-set-context-state-in-app-js-using-usecontext-hook), but it wasn't using NextJS, just React, and the answer there seemed to be that he was trying to use the `useContext` call outside of the component chain he had wrapped in `ContextProvider`. Maybe I'm missing something, but I'm pretty sure that's not my issue.</s>

So, I did the natural debugging thing, and started adding a bunch of `console.log`s. Before I even get to the `<Navbar />` component, it appears that the `setHeader()` call isn't actually updating the state.

Here's an updated `<Header />`:

```
export default function Header({data}) {
    const HeaderData = {
        siteName: data.siteBranding.siteName,
        companyLogo: data.siteBranding.companyLogo,
        menu: data?.menu
    };    
    console.log('Set HeaderData to');
    console.log(HeaderData);

    // In the initial code, I just pulled in setHeader here, but now pulling in header for debugging purposes
    const { header, setHeader } = useHeader();
    setHeader(HeaderData); // various incantations here
    console.log('Just set header, header is');
    console.log(header)
```

But no matter what incantation I use at "various incantations here", the result logged to console is always the same:

```
Set HeaderData to
{
  siteName: 'My Site',
  companyLogo: {
    alt: 'My Site Logo',
    height: 113,
    url: 'https://www.datocms-assets.com/<url>',
    width: 122
  },
  menu: { title: 'primary', menuItems: [ [Object], [Object] ] }
}
Just set header, header is
null
```

I've tried `setHeader(HeaderData)`, which seems most analogous to what he did in that original blog post, but since that wasn't working, I also tried `setHeader({HeaderData})` and `setHeader({...HeaderData})`, but the results are identical.

Why isn't this set setting?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with the code as written. Firstly you shouldn't try to console log the new state value after setting it. It won't work. Calling `setHeader` doesn't change the value of `header` in this call. It causes it to be changed for the next rendering of the component (which will happen immediately).

Secondly, don't use `useEffect` to synchronize your state.

```js
    const HeaderData = {
        siteName: data.siteBranding.siteName,
        companyLogo: data.siteBranding.companyLogo,
        menu: data?.menu
    };

    const { setHeader } = useHeader();

    useEffect(() => {
      setHeader(HeaderData)
    }, [HeaderData]);
```

This code fragment used in any component which is an ancestor of a `HeaderContext` will cause an infinite render loop. The `useEffect` will fire each time `HeaderData` changes. But `HeaderData` is constructed each time the component is rendered. So the `useEffect` will fire each time the component is rendered, and it will call `setHeader` which will force a re-render, which closes the loop.

If you're trying to simply specify the initial state (and not trying to update it in response to some event), simply pass the initial state to the provider component. e.g.

```js
// context/header.js
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react';

const HeaderContext = createContext();

const defaultHeaderState = {
    siteName: data.siteBranding.siteName,
    companyLogo: data.siteBranding.companyLogo,
    menu: data?.menu
};  

export function HeaderProvider({
  initialState = defaultHeaderState,
  children
}) {
    const [header, setHeader] = useState(initialState);
    const value = { header, setHeader };

    return (
        <HeaderContext.Provider value={value}>
            {children}
        </HeaderContext.Provider>
    )
}

export function useHeader() {
    return useContext(HeaderContext);
}
```

Comment: OK. Thanks for the comments, but what's the answer (i.e., what's the right way to update the state for Context if not through useEffect)?

Comment: Probably through some onClick ? If you want the state the have that value initially, just pass it to the useState. I'll edit my answer to explain..

Comment: This is for NextJS and pulling data from a headless CMS for creation of static pages. There is no user interaction (e.g., onClick) to change anything.

Comment: So you just want the data there statically? Just set it in your state.

Comment: As best I understand NextJS (as I said, this is my first time), I think that's what I'm doing. The `pageProps` get filled for each page by the CMS, and Next outputs a static page for each one. In my code above, the portion of pageProps that I want shared across pages and to avoid prop drilling are what I'm putting in the Context.

Answer (score 0):

Chad's answer was definitely right, directionally — don't use `useEffect`, and "just set it". The problem was,

*how to set it from data coming in via `getStaticProps`*?

The answer was to extract it at the `_app.js` level from `pageProps`, and **pass it directly as a value to the context provider**. In fact, there's no longer even a reason to use `setState`:

```
// pages/_app.js
import { HeaderProvider } from '../lib/context/header';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {

 // pull the initial data out of pageProps
 const headerData = {
    urgentBanner: pageProps.data?.urgentBanner,
    siteName: pageProps.data.siteBranding.siteName,
    companyLogo: pageProps.data.siteBranding.companyLogo,
    menu: pageProps.data?.menu
  }

  return (
    <>
      { /* pass it as a value to the context provider */ }
      <HeaderProvider value={headerData}>
        <Header { ...pageProps } /> 
      </HeaderProvider>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </>
  )
}
```

and the context provider component gets simplified down to

```
// context/header.js
import { createContext, useContext } from 'react';

const HeaderContext = createContext();

export function HeaderProvider({value, children}) {

    return (
        <HeaderContext.Provider value={value}>
            {children}
        </HeaderContext.Provider>
    )
}

export function useHeader() {
    return useContext(HeaderContext);
}
```

Finally, everywhere you want to use it (in a descendent of the context provider, `HeaderProvider`), you can just:

```
import { useHeader } from '../lib/context/header';
const headerData = useHeader();
```